# ViewController Segue Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I would like to achieve same functionality that I have already done in iOS. I first create segue between `viewcontroller to viewcontroller` by `Ctrl-click` and `drag` , after that I use `segue identifier` to reach the `destinationviewcontroller`.

However, in Xamarin if there is no button, you cannot add segue with `Ctrl-click` and `drag`. I would like to know is there a way to achieve the same functionality that `native iOS` provides? 
I followed the following tutorial but it is based on `button segue`, not `viewcontroller to viewcontroller segue`. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_storyboards/

`Xamarin`

```
 public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
     {
        UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard", null);
        SecondViewController sVC = (SecondViewController)board.InstantiateViewController ("SecondViewController");
        ctrl.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical;
        iv.PresentViewController(sVC,true,null);
      }
```

// in iOS code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isDetail" sender:self];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"isDetail"]) {

           SecondViewController *fVC = [segue destinationViewController];

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some source code illustrating your problem?

Comment: Hello Ortomala, I have updated my question with code snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a segue between two view controllers by `Ctrl-Click`ing and `dragging` from the grey area at the bottom of the source view controller to the second view controller (see image). The properties for the segue (such as the transition style) can be edited in the properties pane like any other control on the storyboard surface.

[image]

When you want to use the segue, it is easy enough:

```
PerformSegue ("detailSegue", this);
```

where `detailSegue` is the segue identifer as set in the storyboard. Then in `PrepareForSegue` do your initialisation:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    if (segue.Identifier == "detailSegue") {

        SecondViewController = segue.DestinationViewController;

        // do your initialisation here

    }
}
```

Presumedly, (looking at your sample code), you'd like the initialisation for the destination view controller to be dependent on the row selected in in the table view. For that, you can either add a field to your view controller to hold the selected row, or "abuse" the `sender` parameter of PerformSegue to pass the NSIndexPath through:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    this.PerformSegue ("detailSegue", indexPath); // pass indexPath as sender
}
```

and then:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    var indexPath = (NSIndexPath)sender; // this was the selected row

    // rest of PrepareForSegue here
}
```

Comment: Thanks rdavisau, now I could able to segue two viewcontrollers.

Comment: It looks like you are calling this.PerformSegue inside your UITableViewSource in the row selected method. This does not seem to work for me, this.PerformSegue is not available and it does not make sense that the UITableViewSource class would have access to it. Where are you calling that? Thanks.

Comment: This code uses a `UITableViewController` (a `UIViewController` subclass), which comes with a `UITableView` in the root view and acts as its datasource and delegate. It exposes the datasource and delegate callbacks as `virtual` methods, which is why they are overriden here - so `this` actually refers to the `UITableViewController` instance.