# How to pass object using segue

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, uiview, xamarin

I carry a uitableview with a collection of objects.
And when I click on a UITableViewCell open another UIView.
But I wanted to send the object that is in UITableViewCell for this new UIView and there to show their details.
I followed to answer this question to load another view: [ViewController Segue Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804690/viewcontroller-segue-xamarin)
I am very grateful if someone help

[image]

Comment: Try https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIViewController.PrepareForSegue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override [PrepareForSegue](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_storyboards/#Transferring_Data_with_Segues) in your ViewController to set parameters on the destination controller.  You will need to define public methods or properties on the destination controller that allow you to pass parameters:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
      if (segue.Identifier == "TaskSegue") { // set in Storyboard
        var navctlr = segue.DestinationViewController as TaskDetailViewController;
        if (navctlr != null) {

          // some public method you create in your destination controller
          navctlr.SetTask (this, item); 
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions, first one is to use 
prepareForSegue(_:sender:) method:

> Discussion 
>   The default implementation of this method does nothing; you
>   can override it to pass relevant data to the new view controller or
>   window controller, based on the context of the segue. The segue object
>   describes the transition and includes references to both controllers
>   involved in the segue.
>
> Segues can be triggered from multiple sources, so use the information
>   in the segue and sender parameters to disambiguate between different
>   logical paths in your app. For example, if the segue originated from a
>   table view, the sender parameter would identify the cell that the user
>   clicked. You could use that information to set the data on the
>   destination view controller.

In thi case you need to "save" an object that you want to pass in didSelectRow:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   self.currentObjectToPass = .. some object from array or somewhere else..
}
```

And then set it to next vc:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton*)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"bookingDetailsSegue"]) {
        self.nextVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        self.nextVC.objectToPass = self.currentObjectToPass;
    }
}
```

The other way is to refuse of using of segues and get vc by its storyboardID.

This way you need 
instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:) method:

> Return Value The view controller corresponding to the specified
>   identifier string. If no view controller is associated with the
>   string, this method throws an exception.
>
> Discussion You use this method to create view controller objects that
>   you want to manipulate and present programmatically in your
>   application. Before you can use this method to retrieve a view
>   controller, you must explicitly tag it with an appropriate identifier
>   string in Interface Builder.
>
> This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller
>   each time you call it.

Then your code will look like this:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       self.nextVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextVCID"];

       self.nextVC.objectToPass = = .. some object from array or somewhere else..
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.nextVC animated:YES];
    }
```

And don't forget to set vc identifier (Storyboard ID) in IB here:

[image]

Comment: For future readers using Xamarin.IOS. I put a field that stores the last selected item in the TableViewController. Then in the TableViewSource, I overrode the OnRowSelected, and set that field's value to the last selected item.  Back in the controller, I overrode the PrepareForSegue, and checked if the last selected field was null. If not, I checked if the destination view controller was the correct class, if so, I called a public method to pass the object to it. Finally, I drew an outlet from the cell to the 2nd view controller, selecting "Selection segue:Show". Thanks for the great answer